tar command in backup script throws cannot open destination tgz file when run from cron
I have two external USB hard drives. I have a script that executes tar on one external drive files and puts the tgz another USB external drive. like below :
/usr/bin/tar czpf /Volumes/BackupTmp/burocracia-$DATE_STR.tgz /Volumes/Burocracia
$DATE_STR is a variable defined at the top of the script.
When run from the command line fine. When run from cron of my regular user, the tar commands print :
tar: Failed to open '/Volumes/BackupTmp/burocracia-2024-10-15.tgz'
the cron configuration is :
0 23 */1 * * /bin/bash -c "/Users/dlsa/bin/backup-attached-disks.sh 1> /Users/dlsa/backup-attached-disks.out 2>&1"
I have looked on the Internet, and always sugestions to put it in root's crontab.
But I don't want to do that. I want it to run under my user. Which it is, I've checked in the logs.
Thanks,
Regards

Programs need to be granted access to removable drives (and many other areas that may contain personal data); you probably granted access to Terminal, but not cron. See "Crontab Operation not permitted" and "What and how does macOS Mojave implement to restrict applications access to personal data?".

Adding Full Disk Access permission to cron totally worked:

Choose Apple menu > System Settings.

Select  Privacy & Security and then Full Disk Access.

Scroll down and press the plus sign.
You may need to enter your password.

Press ⌘shiftG

Type /usr/sbin.

Select cron from the list and press Open.


Cron now executes my bash script.
